# Geolocation PositionChanged Xamarin essentials (not planned)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.essentials

I have ported most of my stuff to xamarin essentials,however I have noticed that geolocation "PositionChanged" event listener has not made it in xamarin essentials and there is no plan for it and I need it!!

Do I need to revert to the "OLD" PLUGIN to use positionchanged or can i use both xamarin essentials (getlastknownPositionAsync) and the Geolocation plugin just to use "PositionChanged" event?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, there is not currently support for that event in Xamarin Essentials. That is not cool. However, you can still use the "old" plugin to listen to that particular event. They can work together without issues. Just use the ones you need accordingly.

Comment: so are you saying i can still use the xamarinessentials "GetLastKnownLocationAsync" and indipendently use the plugin "geolocation" to just listening to positionchanged . Is this what you are saying?

Comment: That doesn't seem the case. I added Xam.Plugin.Geolocator v 4.5.0.6 and ap doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: @Mariusz they will compile. You need to specify classes explicitly if there are compilation errors. I assume same names are used for both of them partly - Essentials and Plugin Geolocation.